# Dot net nuke changing the content of pane dynamically

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

Hey friends i am new to Dotnet nuke. Here I need to create one section which is updated automatically. AS for example  Employee of the month section need to be updated automatically and also should have history. For that i thought to create one page named Employee and than create sub pages with employee info. Then i need to copy the information of that page to the employee of the month section automatiacally. Whenever new sub pages is added i need to update in the employee of the month section.

I am stuck on it. Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a page per each employee and put all their biography information in an HTML module it will get versioned automatically.

You can then use a shadow module like [Inventua](http://www.inventua.com/Default.aspx?tabid=64&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) that you can add this module to your 'employee of the month' page. With this module you can point it to any HTML module on your site and it shadows / clones the content to that page. So when the employee of the month changes you just go edit the settings of this module and point it to another employee.

That module is pretty old but I think it actually still works in later versions of DNN 5 and 6. Might be a more popular shadow module now.